# Display future posts in search

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I have a search page that display's news items using the loop below, how can I only show posts with the status "future"?

```
                        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
                            <div class="news-item" onclick="location.href='<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>'">
                                <h2><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_time('d.m.Y'); ?> / <?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                <p class="news-page">
                                    <?php if (get_field('description') != "") { ?>
                                        <?php echo the_field('description'); ?>
                                    <?php } else { 
                                        $newscontent = get_the_content();
                                        $newscontent_str = strip_tags($newscontent, '');
                                        echo substr($newscontent_str,0,250) . "…";
                                    } ?>    
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ( 'future' === get_post_status( the_ID() ) ) : ?>
    <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <div class="news-item" onclick="location.href='<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>'">
            <h2><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_time('d.m.Y'); ?> / <?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="news-page">
                <?php if (get_field('description') != "") { ?>
                    <?php echo the_field('description'); ?>
                <?php } else { 
                    $newscontent = get_the_content();
                    $newscontent_str = strip_tags($newscontent, '');
                    echo substr($newscontent_str,0,250) . "…";
                } ?>    
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You may also need to alter the search query to include future posts